# Unity - Problem with while loop on embedded coroutines

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Sorry if this is a newbie question, but I looked around and can't find any clue to fix my problem yet.
I am currently encountering a freeze when I try to run two coroutines together.

My end goal is:

- to have one long coroutine representing the duration of a day.
- one other smaller coroutine that will activate repeatedly while the day is not finished.

The two cotourines works fine independantly or when the second coroutine is directly embedded into the first one without the check on the endDay bool.

But when I tried to include the while loop, unity freeze at play (it reaches the 'DayStart.SetActive(true)' of the code below but does not go further).
Thinking the endDay bool being at the end of the first coroutine was probably the reason to the problem, I tried to build two completely independant ones (non-embedded coroutines with only the endDay bool as link between the two) but it didn't go better.

Does someone has an idea on how I could make it work?

For information, here is the code I initially used and that reverted the error. I spare you the detail of the second coroutine as it is quite long and probably not the problem here.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Transaction : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject DayStart;
    public GameObject DayTracker;

    private bool endDay;

    private void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    public void MainDayCycle()
    {
        StartCoroutine(MainDayCycleCO());
    }

    IEnumerator MainDayCycleCO()
    {
        endDay = false;

        // Beginning of day picture
        DayStart.SetActive(true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        DayStart.SetActive(false);

        // [To be completed] Day Tracker bar
        DayTracker.SetActive(true);

        TradeCycle();

        // Lancement de délai de journée et enregistrement de la fin
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(20);
        endDay = true;
    }

    public void TradeCycle()
    {
        while (endDay == false)
        {
            StartCoroutine(TradeCycleCO());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I think you are missing the code with the `while` loop ;) but in general: are you sure you do `yield return` somewhere inside the loop?

Comment: In general please explain or show to us how exactly your methods are called .. currently it is a bit hard to understand the concept

Comment: Indeed! I probably copy and paste too fast. You have the right code now, and not the one I cleaned afterwards.

Comment: And yes, both of them have yield return somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said this one

```
public void TradeCycle()
{
    while (endDay == false)
    {
        StartCoroutine(TradeCycleCO());
    }
}
```

Doesn't have any `yield` and this loop will freeze because nowhere inside the `endDay` is changed!

It sounds like what you rather want to do is (still don't have your `TradeCycleCO` code)

```
// Does this even need to be public?
public void TradeCycle()
{
    StartCoroutine(TradeCycleCO());
}

IEnumerator TradeCycleCO()
{
    while(!endDay)
    {
        // Your code here
        // Make sure something yield returns in here

        // If needed you could also interrupt at certain points via checking again

        // Use that to do e.g. some cleaning up after the loop
        if(endDay) break;

        // or use that to immediately leave the coroutine overall
        if(endDay) yield break;
    }

    // Code that may be executed after the day has ended e.g. for cleaning up stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked and you spared me a lot of headache. Have a nice day!